# Windows-1252 to unicode conversion in perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I have the [ef(cyrillic)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ef_%28Cyrillic%29) character in hex format of Windows-1251.
The value is 0xF4. I want to convert and print the character in perl.
And the way i can do it is via unicode 0x0444.
I am looking for a way to convert 0xF4 to 0x044.
My eventual plan is given a hex value of any character in any encoding, i should be able to convert it into hex value of unicode and finally able to print it. 
But its not working
Below is the code i am using

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use utf8;
use Encode qw(decode encode);

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
my $runtime = chr(0x0444);
   print "theta || ".$runtime." ||";
   my $smiley = "\x{0444}";
   print "theta || ".$smiley." ||";
   my $georgian_an  = pack("U", 0x0444);
   print "theta || ".$georgian_an." ||";

  my $hexstr = "0xF4";
  my $num = hex $hexstr;
  print $num;  # printing the hex value
  my $be_num = pack("N", $num);
  $runtime = decode( "cp1252",$be_num);
  print "\n".$runtime."\n"; # i should have got ф here
```

Output

```
perl mychar_new.pl
theta || ф ||theta || ф ||theta || ф ||244

ô
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is correct – in CP-125**2**, `0xF4` is indeed `ô` ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1252)).

You wanted to specify [CP-125**1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP1251) instead!

```
use Encode 'decode';
my $cp1251 = "\xF4";
my $decoded = decode "cp1251", $cp1251;
print "$decoded\n";
```

Comment: Thanks amon, that helps.
Let me share why i need this.
I am trying to parse a rtf file, the contents for which is ф & in vi it is as below. The rtf mentioned the unicode cpg1252. RTF::TEXT::Converter doesn't work hence using RTF::Tokenizer

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\fromtext \fbidis \deff0{\fonttbl
{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}
{\f1\fmodern Courier New;}
{\f2\fnil\fcharset2 Symbol;}
{\f3\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier New;}
{\f4\fswiss\fcharset204 Arial;}}
{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;}
\uc1\pard\plain\deftab360 \f0\fs20 \htmlrtf{\f4\fs20\htmlrtf0 \'f4\htmlrtf\f0}\htmlrtf0 \par
}